# For how many values of $x$ does $f(x)=\cos x+\cos(\sqrt{2}x)$ attain its absolute minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

> For how many values of $x$ does $$f(x)=\cos x+\cos(\sqrt{2}x)$$ attain its absolute minimum?

**My Attempt:**

Absolute maximum of $f(x)$ is clearly $2$ which occurs when $x=0$. But what should be the approach to obtain absolute minimum.

One can observe that $f(x)$ is bounded, continuous, even and non-periodic so it will achieve its absolute minimum at least twice.

Can we say that it will achieve its minimum(absolute) exactly twice. And if yes what will that minimum be and for what value(s) of $x$ will it occur

Comment: $\cos(x) + \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is also bounded, continuous, even, and non-periodic, but it doesn't _have_ a global minimum. What makes you certain your $f$ has one?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this function does not have a global minimum. I predict that it can get arbitrarily close to $-2$, but never reach it. Irrationality of $\sqrt2$ and a bit of Diophantine approximation, me thinks?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha thinks that the absolute minimum is -2. I'm curious to see if that's correct.

Comment: @ThomasDavis That is not correct. $-2$ is is the infimum of the values. Not the minimum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that cosine is even was a noble effort, but this problem was looking for something different.

Since the minimum of $\cos$ is -1, $f$ cannot attain a value less than $-2$.  Can it attain that value?  If it did, there would have to be some real $x$ such that $x$ and $x\sqrt2$ were odd multiples of $\pi$, but that is impossible since $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

However, we *can* find odd integers $x$ such that $x\sqrt2$ is as close to an odd integer as we please.  (As the comments point out, this is due to the fact that the fractional parts of $x\sqrt2$ are dense in the unit interval, and just trust us if you don't understand what that means.)  Therefore, the range of $f$ is $(-2,2]$, and it has no global minimum at all.

Comment: So had $f(x)$ been defined on some closed interval then absolute minimum would have existed but since it is defined here on $(-\infty,\infty)$ the absolute minimum cannot be ascertained

Comment: Please ignore the above comment

Comment: @Maverick Yes, on a closed interval, 2 would have been an excellent answer.  I would say that the absolute minimum cannot be **attained** on $(-\infty, \infty)$, since "ascertained" implies that it has a minimum whose value we don't know.  In fact, for any local minimum you find, there is a lower local minimum somewhere else.

Comment: Minor nitpick: "since we can get arbitrarily good approximations of $\sqrt 2$" should probably be "since the fractional parts of $n\sqrt 2$ are dense in the unit interval".

Comment: Having a good approximation for $\sqrt2$ is not quite enough. For all $\epsilon>0$ we need to find odd integers $m,n$ such that $|m-n\sqrt2|<\epsilon$. Equivalently
$$\left|\frac mn-\sqrt2\right|<\frac{\epsilon}n.$$ Diophantine approximation to the rescue. In other words, siding with @Troposphere.

Comment: @MatthewDaly.How would you justify your last sentence 'In fact, for any local minimum you find, there is a lower local minimum somewhere else.'

Comment: I agree with these nitpicks.  I wanted to be a little more handwavey since "algebra-precalculus" was listed as one of the tags and I didn't want to bury the questioner in too much real analysis.  I'll edit my answer to point out my intentional simplification.

Comment: @Maverick Since $f$ has no global minimum, then clearly no local minimum is a global minimum.  Thus, for any local minimum, the function attains a lower value somewhere else.  Am I saying something incorrect there?

Comment: @MatthewDaly. Ok I understand that you say this because global minimum does not exist. Thanks

Comment: Beautiful answer except for one thing. 
You say the range is $(-2.2]$, but does this function attain a value $\leq  -1.73$?
It does not. So, how can the range be so?

Comment: @FirdousMala You haven't looked at the plot far enough. See my comment under your answer.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: @MatthewDaly: You're right in what you say your latest comment -- but that reasoning doesn't reach _quite_ all the way to "there's always a lowest local minimum" (though the latter claim is true here too). To wit, there are functions without a global minimum that nevertheless have a smallest _local_ minimum -- for example $\frac{1}{1+(x^2-1)^2}$.

Comment: Exactly how does the density of the fractional parts of multiples o $\sqrt2$ let you show that you can find **odd** integers $m,n$ such that $|m\sqrt2 - n|$ becomes arbitrarily small.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: We seek a $k$ such that $\sqrt2 (\pi+2\pi k)$ is arbitrarily close to an odd multiple of $\pi$. That is the same as $\sqrt 2(1+2k)$ being arbitrarily close to an odd integer, or $\sqrt2/2 + \sqrt2 k - 1$ being arbitrarily close to an integer, or the fractional part of $\sqrt 2 k$ being arbitarily close to the fractional part of $1-\sqrt2/2$.

Comment: @Troposphere. How did you relate $\sqrt{2}(1+2k)$ and $\sqrt{2}/2+\sqrt{2}k-1$

Comment: @Maverick: Ah, the $-1$ in the latter expression should have been $-\frac12$, sorry. Fortunately the rest of the argument doesn't depend on what exactly the constant is.

Comment: @Troposphere. Yes but what is the basis of $\sqrt{2}/2+\sqrt{2}k-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Maverick: I write $\sqrt2(1+2k)\approx 2m+1$, subtract $1$ from both sides, and divide both sides by $2$.